# Neo4j: How can I display labels as nodes?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I have a question about Neo4j. I need to show labels in my graph database as node - like if I have only two types of labels in my database (for example Thing and Person), I want to have 2 extra nodes - Thing and Person with relationships to normal nodes.

Example - I have this:

[image: image 1]

Orange node is Person, red is Thing. So I want to have extra label nodes for every label in graph. So I want this:

[image]

Can be this created automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really want to do that, since a visualization with N nodes would then have N extraneous relationships to the special "label" nodes, making it hard (or even impossible) to see the actual data. Using different colors for different labels is a good compromise.

In any case, the top of the result panel (in the neo4j Browser) tells you which color belongs to which label, so you can already easily get the information you want.

[UPDATE]

However, if you really need to do something like that, there is no "automated" way. But you could use some APOC procedures to create [virtual nodes and relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/#virtual-nodes-rels) that are not stored in the DB,  but which can be visualized.

For example, if your original Cypher query is:

```
MATCH path=(p:Person)-[r:RELTYPE]->(t:Thing)
RETURN *
```

you can use this query to generate the appropriate virtual nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH path=(p:Person)-[r:RELTYPE]->(t:Thing)
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths, COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS ps, COLLECT(DISTINCT t) AS ts
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['V_Label'], {label: 'Person'}) YIELD node AS pLabel
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['V_Label'], {label: 'Thing'}) YIELD node AS tLabel
UNWIND ps AS person
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(person, 'IS', {}, pLabel) YIELD rel AS pRel
WITH paths, ts, pLabel, tLabel, COLLECT(pRel) AS pRels
UNWIND ts AS thing
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(thing, 'IS', {}, tLabel) YIELD rel AS tRel
RETURN *
```

A sample resulting visualization:

[image]

Comment: I actually need to do that, because of academic reasons - the database is part of my diploma thesis. So have you any idea how can I do that? Thanks ;)

Comment: Yeah, my solution will be more complex, but thank you very much for info about virtual nodes --> I think thats the thing I need ;)